# How to remove specific ticks on pgfplots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have this diagram that I am trying to draw:

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=0, xmax=1,
    ymin=0, ymax=1,
    axis lines=center,
    axis on top=true,
    axis y line=none,
    domain=0:1,
    xtick={0.1, 0.25, 0.4, 0.6, 0.75, 0.9},
    xticklabels={$a_{1}$, $\cdots$ , $a_{n}$, $a^{\prime}_{1}$, $\cdots$ , $a^{\prime}_{m}$}
    ]
    \addplot[mark=none, black, thick] coordinates {(0,0.5) (1,0.5)};
    \addplot[mark=none, black, thick, dotted] coordinates {(0.1,0) (0.1,0.4)};
    \addplot[mark=none, black, thick, dotted] coordinates {(0.4,0) (0.4,0.25)};
    \addplot[mark=none, black, thick, dotted] coordinates {(0.6,0) (0.6,0.65)};
    \addplot[mark=none, black, thick, dotted] coordinates {(0.9,0) (0.9,0.9)};
    \node at (axis cs:0.05, 0.55){$x$};
    \addplot[only marks] 
table {
 0.1 0.4
 0.4 0.25
 0.6 0.65
 0.9 0.9
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The outcome, right now, looks like this:

[image]

That is almost what I want, but t would be better if I could remove the ticks just above the ellipsis: how can I do that? I tried using `xtick style={draw=none}`, but that removes all the ticks.

Comment: See `extra x ticks={...}`(page 340 pgfplots manual).

Comment: Unrelated, but since `pgfplots` loads `tikz` already, you can safely remove the latter. Rather, you sould put `\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}`.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thanks! As Jasper Habicht shows in more detail in his answer, that  was indeed the solution.

Comment: @JasperHabicht I have done so, and got rid of an annoying warning message I did not quite understand, thank you!

Comment: @AnyDisplayName PGFPlots evolved over time (as most software does) and along came certain syntax changes. In order to keep backwards compatibility, the package maintainers decided to let the user specify which version they want to use by setting the `compat` value. If you set the value to `newest`, the latest version will be chosen. PGFPlots warns you if you did not specify this, since it will then stick to the most compatible version that does, however, not come with the latest syntax, so some features might be inaccessible. It is probably always a good idea to set the `compat` value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been suggested in the comments, try using `extra x ticks` for the ellipses which you can style individually:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=0, xmax=1,
    ymin=0, ymax=1,
    axis lines=center,
    axis on top=true,
    axis y line=none,
    domain=0:1,
    xtick={0.1, 0.4, 0.6, 0.9},
    xticklabels={$a_{1}$, $a_{n}$, $a^{\prime}_{1}$, $a^{\prime}_{m}$},
    extra x ticks={0.25, 0.75},
    extra x tick style={tick style={draw=none}},
    extra x tick labels={$\cdots$, $\cdots$}
]
    \addplot[mark=none, black, thick] coordinates {(0,0.5) (1,0.5)};
    \addplot[mark=none, black, thick, dotted] coordinates {(0.1,0) (0.1,0.4)};
    \addplot[mark=none, black, thick, dotted] coordinates {(0.4,0) (0.4,0.25)};
    \addplot[mark=none, black, thick, dotted] coordinates {(0.6,0) (0.6,0.65)};
    \addplot[mark=none, black, thick, dotted] coordinates {(0.9,0) (0.9,0.9)};
    \node at (0.05, 0.55) {$x$};
    \addplot[only marks] table {
        0.1 0.4
        0.4 0.25
        0.6 0.65
        0.9 0.9
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Also note that (assuming that you have an up-to-date installation of TeX) adding `\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}` allows you to omit `axis cs:` inside the `axis` environment.

Comment: Yes, that works, thanks!